# Must plot of Newton interpolation polynomial match completely the plot of original function and Lagrange interpolation polynomial on the interval?

Tags: python, math, interpolation, numerical-methods

I have homework where I'm asked to build Newton and Lagrange interpolation polynomials. I had no troubles with Lagrange polynomial but with Newton polynomial arises one problem: while Lagrange interpolation polynomial and original function match completely with each other, Newton Interpolation doesn't do this.
[Here is the plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2couA.png)

If I remember correctly, Newton and Lagrange polynomial interpolation are different ways to represent the same polynomial and they should match the original function at the interval of interpolation completely.

I thought that Newton coefficients were calculated wrongly, so I found another divided difference function. I tried both function and [they gave me the same results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3YJ7.png)

I'm stuck at this moment. I still think that there is something wrong with calculating divided differences functions, but I can't see the mistake.

Any suggestions, please?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate  import lagrange


# func from https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter17.05-Newtons-Polynomial-Interpolation.html
def divided_diff(x, y):
    n = len(y)
    coef = np.zeros([n, n])
    coef[:,0] = y  
    for j in range(1,n):
        for i in range(n-j):
            coef[i][j] = \
           (coef[i+1][j-1] - coef[i][j-1]) / (x[i+j]-x[i])           
    return coef


def coeff(x, y):
    n = len(x)
    arr = y.copy()
    for i in range(1, n):
        arr[i:n] = (arr[i:n] - arr[i - 1]) / (x[i:n] - x[i - 1])
    return arr   


# 1st range
x_values = np.array([0, np.pi/6, np.pi/3, np.pi/2], float)
y_values = np.array([1, np.sqrt(3)/2, 1/2, 0], float)


print(coeff(x_values, y_values))
print(divided_diff(x_values, y_values)[0,:])


# Show polynomials
newton_coefficients = divided_diff(x_values, y_values)[0,:]
newton = np.poly1d(newton_coefficients[::-1])
lagrange_poly = lagrange(x_values, y_values)
print(f"Here is our Lagrange interpolating polynomial:\n{lagrange_poly}\n")
print(f"Here is our Newton interpolating polynomial:\n{newton}\n")
```

Comment: My interpolation interval is from 0 to pi/2

Comment: Yes, I've seen that now. The Newton coefficients are not simply polynomial coefficients for a monomial basis, you need to apply the full Newton interpolation formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you computed the Newton coefficients correctly. However, these are not monomial coefficients, the Newton interpolation formula is

```
p(x) = f(x_0) + f[x_0,x_1]*(x-x_0) + f[x_0,x_1,x_2]*(x-x_0)*(x-x_1) + 
          ... + f[x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1}]*(x-x_0)*(x-x_1)*...*(x-x_{n-2})
```

You would have to construct the polynomial like the Newton did the Horner scheme,

```
newton = 0
for ck,xk in zip(newton_coefficients[::-1],x_values[::-1]):
    newton = newton*np.poly1d([1,-xk]) + np.poly1d([ck])
```

Answer (score 0):

I infer from your plot that you just used two interpolation points (common between the cosine curve and the two polynomials).

The interpolation polynomial by n points is unique (Lagrange and Newton coincide) iff its degree does not exceed n-1. In fact, you should have used a linear model.